# What are the disadvantages of hardware accelerated html?

Tags: html, hardware-acceleration

Right now I'm testing on an Iphone 5 and everytime I add hardware acceleration (`translatez(0)`) on an element it seems to dramatically increase the performance while I can't figure out anything negative.

- What are the disadvantages of putting all elements into hardware accelerated mode?
- I noticed some z-ordering issues between hardware- and non-hardware accelerated elements. What other disadvantages should I pay attention to?
- How is this with other devices and browser, like Android or Windows Phone?
- I guess the answer to this question will follow from the answer above, but why isn't everything harware accelerated by default?

Answer (score 0):

I had 2 times a problem with the hardware acceleration.
First in Firefox, that just doesn't show radial gradients (on some computers).
And once in Android Webview, where I got one some devices flickering and slowdowns.

So, my experiences with hardware acceleration: it's sometime just more error-prone.

Answer (score 0):

One common bug I have seen when enabling "hardware acceleration" for elements that might contain a lot of children or occupy big portion of the screen is that some browsers might not render it at all leaving you with big white spot in the middle of your screen.

I have seen this bug mostly as a result of optimization of a responsive web page, where everything works flawless on small screen and then it does not on desktop Windows with Chrome for instance. I think this depends on OS and graphics adapter, but I have never dig into it much more. The solution usually is to narrow down the usage of hardware acceleration just to the portions of DOM you really need to.